# Store first parameter value in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I want to store the first value obtained by a parameter across reports in one textbox.

The parameter value will change each time and all I want to do is to capture the first initial value and show in report.

I tried storing the parameter value as read only variable and didn't work.

Any suggestions on this is really appreciated.

Comment: how do you input the parameter? user entry or sql query?

Comment: @Jayvee - User entry

Comment: So if a user runs the report with parameter = 'a' and then changes the parameter to 'b' and refresh you want to keep 'a' somewhere. Is this correct?

Comment: @Jayvee - That is correct. I want to keep `'a'` somewhere.

Comment: the only way I can think of is by accessing the view ExecutionLog2 on the report server database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reporting parameter saving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29624599/reporting-parameter-saving)