# How do I programmatically build Eloquent queries based on a custom data structure saved in a persistent storage?

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm building a reporting tool for my Laravel app that will allow users to create reports and save them for later use.

Users will be able to select from a pre-defined list to modify the query, then run the report and save it.

Having never done this before, I was just wondering if it is ok to save the query in the database? This would allow the user to select a saved report and execute the query.

Comment: Only a select group will be authorised to use the reporting feature. But I'd rather not trust anyone. Would it be better to just save the chosen parameters rather than the full query?

Comment: What you save doesn't matter, it's more so how you generate the query.  Maybe you can give a code sample of how it would work.

Answer (score 2):

One approach that would be easier / more robust than the suggested approach of saving queries to the database would be build a Controller that constructs the queries based on user input.

You could validate server side that the query parameters match the predefined list of options and then use Eloquent's QueryBuilder to programatically build the queries.

Actual code examples are hard to provide based off of your question however, as it's very broad and doesn't contain any specific examples.

Comment: This doesn't allow the user o save the query though for future use, does it?

Comment: @showFocus - you could store a query profile that is just a record of the parameters

Answer (score 1):

You essentially need to build a converter between your storage mechanism and your data model in PHP. A code example would not add much value because you need to build it based on your needs.

You need to build a data structure (ideally using JSON in this case, since it's powerful enough for this) that defines all the query elements in a way that your business logic is able to read and convert in Eloquent queries.

I have done something similar in the past but for some simple scenarios, like defining variables for queries, instead of actual query elements.

This is how I'd do it, for example:

```
{
    table: 'users',
    type: 'SELECT',
    fields: ['firstname AS fName', 'lastname AS lName'],
    wheres: [
        is_admin: false,
        is_registered: true
    ]
}
```

converts to:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->where('is_admin', false)
    ->where('is_registered', true)
    ->get(['firstname AS fName', 'lastname AS lName']);
```

which converts to:

```
SELECT firstname AS fName, lastname AS lName WHERE is_admin = false AND is_registered = true
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's an answer about Saving Report Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29624599/reporting-parameter-saving) to a db but from a SQL Server Report Service (SSRS) angle.

But it's still a generic enough EAV structure to work for any parameter datatype (strings, ints, dates, etc.).

You might want to skip Eloquent and use mysql stored procedures. Then you only need to save the list of parameters you'd pass to each.

Like the preferred output type (e.g. .pdf, .xlsx, .html), and who to email it to, and who has permission to run it.